# How to make bin script available for npm package installed locally

Tags: node.js, npm, bin

I read on the npm documentation that you can't use bin scripts of locally installed packages.

So, how `gulp` can be launched as bin command when installed locally?
What's making it available when locally installed, I reviewed the `gulp` `package.json` and the bin scripts, I don't found any answer.

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if your problem is solved. Otherwise, let us know what is not working yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From NPMJS documentation:](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin)

> To use this, supply a bin field in your package.json which is a map of command name to local file name. On install, npm will symlink that file into prefix/bin for global installs, or ./node_modules/.bin/ for local installs.

So, your locally installed packages binaries will be executable like this

```
./bin/node_modules/.bin/the_binary
```

This is if you want to launch the binary directly. Or, as specified in [the scripts part of the documentation:](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script)

> In addition to the shell's pre-existing PATH, npm run adds node_modules/.bin to the PATH provided to scripts.

Thus, you can simply write a wrapper script like

```
scripts: {
  "build": "the_binary"
}
```

and call your script like this

```
npm run build
```

**Bonus**

> As of npm@2.0.0, you can use custom arguments when executing scripts. The special option -- is used by getopt to delimit the end of the options. npm will pass all the arguments after the -- directly to your script:

```
npm run test -- --grep="pattern"
```

Comment: So, I cannot install a package (gulp as example) locally and run the bin command without aving a global install?

Cause I have installed Gulp locally and I can run `gulp default` bin command without having `Gulp` installed globally.

The problem is maybe in my bash_profile... I dont know why I can run Gulp but not my custom bin command without global install and the documentation you linked seems to say it is totaly normal.

Comment: No, you should'nt be able to do that. You can run `npm list -g` to see which packages are installed globally and `which gulp` to see where the binary is located.

Comment: I confirm, the problem was from my bash_profile... Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use lpx https://www.npmjs.com/package/lpx to

- run a binary found in the local node_modules/.bin folder
- run a binary found in the node_modules/.bin of a workspace root from anywhere in the workspace

lpx does not download any package if the binary is not found locally (ie not like npx)

Example : `lpx tsc -b -w` will run `tsc -b -w` with the local typescript package