# How to make NPM package like nodemon

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-publish

I made a package for myself which merges multiple files to single file before starting server. Now I want to publish this package to npmjs.com but this package will not be used in the app like `const mergeFiles = require('mergeFiles')`. This package will be used more likely `nodemon` package so people will be able to call my package like `node mergeFiles && node server` with `npm start` command. Tutorials always show how to make it with `require` style so it doesn't work for me.

Comment: If by "like nodemon" you just mean with an executable, see e.g. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#bin, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39162517/3001761, ... (here's a simple one I put together recently: https://github.com/textbook/build-info).

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at the [repo of nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) to get an idea of how it works.